# Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) Тест первый запустился прошел

Tags: c#, selenium, macos, selenium-webdriver, mac

проблема в чем: поставил chromedriver через консоль, тест первый раз запустился прошел, следующий сразу упал, потом постоянно такая ошибка, возможно кто нибуть подскажет, юзаю мак. Спасибо

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : 
   unknown error: 
        Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) 
        (The process started from chrome location 
        /usr/local/bin/chromedriver is no longer running, 
        so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
        TearDown : 
          System.NullReferenceException : 
            Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

настройки хром драйвера

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.BinaryLocation = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.kenst.com/2015/03/installing-chromedriver-on-mac-osx/ решение вот здесь, вруг кому то будет полезно. Нужно поменять на папку документы, туда копировать chromedriver